# How to solve this error "AddressAccessDeniedException" when using Azure?

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a WCF Service hosted in a ASP.NET web application, running in Azure as a App Service.

There are no errors when I run this Project in my local machine. But when deployed to Azure, I have the following error:

> [AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL
>   http://+:80/docs/. Your process does not have access rights to this
>   namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for
>   details).]

There are plenty of posts about this error regarding of local machines, but not related to azure. Theu suggest to run netsh to give permission to url, but I dont know how to do this in Azure.

In fact I am trying to use Swagger for WCF implementation, and the error occurs in this code:

Global.asax.cs:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Swagger
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api-docs", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SwaggerWcfEndpoint)));
    var swaggerHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(SwaggerWcfEndpoint));
    swaggerHost.Open();
  }
```

Web.config:

```
<services>
  <service name="SwaggerWcf.SwaggerWcfEndpoint">
    <endpoint address="http://totvsrmwebapp.azurewebsites.net/docs" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SwaggerWcf.ISwaggerWcfEndpoint" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Here you are the Stack Trace:

```
'[HttpListenerException (0x5): Access is denied]
   System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config() +333
   System.Net.HttpListener.Start() +297
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen() +651

[AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/docs/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).]
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen() +1473
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener) +296
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback) +122
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +64
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +67
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +308
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +61
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +308
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +136
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +308
   RMWCFWebApp.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +236

[HttpException (0x80004005): HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/docs/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9982013
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/docs/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9963380
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your issue. Based on my experience, Azure web app does not give us permission to register url "http://totvsrmwebapp.azurewebsites.net/docs". If you want to do this, I would recommend you use Azure cloud service, and execute command (netsh http add urlacl url=) in start up task. For more information about cloud service, please refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/cloud-services/). And have a look at [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks/) to know how to use start up task.

Comment: I found this as well: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSAzureStartupTask-ebb574a0